# .htaccess processing certain letters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file with a rewrite rule that works pretty much everywhere, but when I uploaded the site to a GoDaddy hosting environment, certain letters from the URL disappear. Has anyone ever come across this before? If so, what is the solution?

Thanks in advance!

My .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And when I paste URL parameters, here's what shows up

```
Array ( [0] => privy_poliy )
```

Instead of

```
Array ( [0] => privacy_policy )
```

Comment: Looks really odd. Can you show the incoming URLs?

Comment: Incoming URL example - http://domain.com/privacy_policy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have mod_speling loaded on the failing server and that stray miss-spelling exists in the filesystem?